# Android Notification use PendingIntent not new one

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

I have implemented some notifications in my application. It seems that everytime I click on the notification it starts a new intent. The goal is to bring the application in the foreground because it is still in background (so not killed).

How can I achieve this?

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class), 0);
    long[] vibration = new long[]{100, 250}; 

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setTicker(msg)
    .setLights(Color.WHITE, 300, 600)
    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.new_msg))
    .setVibrate(vibration)
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring the application to the front, use the following intent in the Pending Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

This'll resume the application if not already killed or open the ChatActivity if it has been killed.

Comment: Mhm I have a String in ChatActivity. This String has some text from the chat in it. After clicking on the notification the Activity comes up but the string is empty. I don't know why :o To check this I put System.out.println(bla); in onResume() what normally should be called when I click on the notification, right?

Comment: Why not just put log messages inside onCreate and onResume and see if they execute ? But I think onResume will be called for sure.

Comment: Ok I think it is working now :o I don't know what the mistake was but now with your code I finally get the String like it was before the notification and that's what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: :) However, the activity behaves differently when back button is pressed and when home button is pressed and the app goes into background, and you might lose your variable value at times. So, keep a check!